# MySQL not storing floating point numbers

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to store a floating point number in a MySQL database through python, but it's rounding it off to whole integers.

I've tried the DECIMAL, FLOAT and DOUBLE data types with the appropriate values but it hasn't worked

```py
def insert_row(id, today_date, year, month_number, month_name, day, day_name, mood):
  cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + str(id) + " (date DATE PRIMARY KEY, year YEAR, month_number INTEGER(2), month_name VARCHAR(10), day INTEGER(2), day_name VARCHAR(10), mood DECIMAL(4,3))")

  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + str(id) + " (date, year, month_number, month_name, day, day_name, mood) VALUES('" + today_date + "', '" + year + "', " + str(month_number) + ", '" + month_name + "', " + str(day) + ", '" + day_name + "', 0.5) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mood=0.5")
  mydb.commit()
```

So I expect the value of the mood column to be 0.5 but the actual value is always 1

Comment: Have you checked what column types you have actually created in the table ?

Answer (score 0):

convert to 'query ' + float(0.5) + 'rest of the query'